# When a third-party C function returns a pointer, should you free it yourself?

Tags: c, memory-management, return-value

There are many functions (especially in the POSIX library) that return pointers to almost-necessarily freshly allocated data. Their manpages don't say if you should free them, or if there's some obscure mechanism at play (like returning a pointer to a static buffer, or something along these lines).

For instance, the [`inet_ntoa`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/inet_ntoa.3.asp) function returns a `char*` most likely out from nowhere, but the manpage doesn't say how it was allocated. I ended up using [`inet_ntop`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/inet_ntop.3.asp) instead because at least I knew where the destination allocation came from.

What's the standard rule for C functions returning pointers? Who's responsible for freeing their memory?

Comment: inet_ntoa() and family are depricated in favour of inet_ntop() and family() because the former do not support IP-V6 addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a standard rule. Some functions require your to pass a pointer in, and they fill data into that space (e.g., `sprintf`). Others return the address of a static data area (e.g., many of the functions in `<time.h>`). Others still allocate memory when needed (e.g., `setvbuf`).

About the best you can do is *hope* that the documentation tells you what pointers need to be freed. You shouldn't normally attempt to free pointers it returns unless the documentation tells you to. Unless you're passing in the address of a buffer for it to use, or it specifies that you need to free the memory, you should generally assume that it's using a static data area. This means (among other things) that you should assume the value *will* be changed by any subsequent calls to the same routine. If you're writing multithreaded code, you should generally assume that the function is *not* really thread-safe -- that you have a shared data area that requires synchronization, so you should acquire a lock, call the function, copy the data out of its data area, and only then release the lock.

Answer (score 12):

You have to read the documentation, there is no other way. My man page for `inet_ntoa` reads:

> The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

So in this case you must not attempt to free the returned pointer.

Comment: ...and many pages say "...returns a newly allocated buffer..." which means that the user *should* free it when they are done.

Comment: @Martin: sorry that was a general comment about the language used in man pages, and was not intended to be directly responsive to the OPs situation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard rule. Ideally, a standard library function such as inet_ntoa comes with a man
page which describes the "rules of engagement" i.e. the interface of the function - arguments expected, return values in case of success and errors as well as the semantics of dealing with allocated memory.

From the man page of inet_ntoa:

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the
>   Internet host address in, given in
>   network byte order, to a string in
>   IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.  The
>   string is returned in a statically
>   allocated buffer, which subsequent
>   calls will overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my machine (Mac OS X 10.6) the final sentence of the manpage, under `BUGS` is:

> The string returned by inet_ntoa() resides in a static memory area.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea that "many" functions in POSIX return pointers this way is mistaken. Your example, `inet_ntoa` is **not in POSIX** and was deliberately excluded because it's deprecated and broken.

The number of standard functions which return pointers to allocated memory is actually rather small, and most of the ones that do so provide a special complementary function you're required to use for freeing the memory (for instance, `fopen` and `fclose`, `getaddrinfo` and `freeaddrinfo`, or `regcomp` and `regfree`). Simply calling `free` on the pointer returned would be very bad; at best you'd end up with serious memory leaks, and at worst it could lead to unexpected crashes (for instance if the library was keeping the objects it allocated in a linked list).

Whether a function is part of the system library or a third-party library, it should document the expected usage of any pointers it returns (and whether/how it's necessary to free them). For standard functions, the best reference on this matter is [POSIX itself](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html). You could also check the man pages for your particular system. If the code is part of a third-party library, it should come with documentation (perhaps in man pages, in the header files, or in a comprehensive document on library usage). A well-written library will provide special functions to free objects it allocates, so as to avoid introducing dependencies on the way it's (currently) implemented to code that uses the library.

As far as the nonstandard `inet_ntoa` and similar legacy functions go, they return pointers to internal static buffers. This makes them unsuitable for use with threads or in library code (which must take care not to destroy the caller's state unless it'd documented as doing so). Often the documentation for such functions will say that they are **not required to be thread-safe**, that they are **not reentrant**, or that they **may return a pointer to an internal static buffer which may be overwritten by subsequent calls** to the function. Many people, myself included, believe that such functions should not be used at all in modern code.