# Where are strings returned from functions in libc allocated?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libc

I started some socket programming, and I ran across the function inet_ntoa . The function has the prototype `char * inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);`.

So how/where will this string be allocated? Am I expected to call free on it?

Comment: (Very) Short answer that doesn't really answer your question : inset_ntop is the new standard. ntoa is deprecated.

Comment: See this (duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647953/when-a-third-party-c-function-returns-a-pointer-should-you-free-it-yourself

Comment: At the end of the man page in the bugs section : `The string returned by inet_ntoa() resides in a static memory area.`

Comment: I think the moral is that with formal standards, if the documentation doesn't say how to free any memory associated with the return value, or otherwise state how it was allocated, then that means you don't have to free it. Personally I try to make that explicit when writing function documentation, because when I see no instructions in my colleagues' documentation it just makes me suspect they might have forgotten to mention it.

Comment: @Steve: Nowadays with threads being standard everywhere but bare-bones C, and even in the upcoming C1x standard, it's pretty much mandatory for a function's specification to document the storage of the buffer returned, or at least document that the function is non-thread-safe (and likewise non-library-safe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`inet_ntoa(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa):

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the
>   Internet host address in given in
>   network byte order to a string in
>   standard numbers-and-dots notation.
>   The string is returned in a **statically allocated buffer**, which subsequent
>   calls will overwrite

So, no.

Comment: Although note that this quote is from the Linux manpage (hence presumably relates to glibc), whereas the question links to the BSD manpage. Posix does not *guarantee* that subsequent calls will overwrite the same buffer, as linux apparently does, although you have to think that's the obvious way to implement it on any *nix ;-) Posix does say, "The inet_ntoa() function need not be reentrant", which is standardese for "it's allowed (among other things) to return a pointer to a static buffer".

Comment: @Steve: While it doesn't say that it has to return a pointer to a static buffer, this and returning a pointer to a `malloc`-obtained buffer whose address is stored in a static variable are just about the only possible implementations. I suppose in the latter case it could actually use a thread-local variable to store the address and make itself thread-safe, but it still would not be safe for use from library code (where it would corrupt its caller's state).

Comment: @R..: indeed. Various "silly" options are also permitted, such as returning a pointer to the LRU of a pool of static buffers. This would give a limited appearance of library-safety without actually achieving it. Really I was just pointing out that linux documents more of the implementation than BSD does, I didn't intend to suggest that BSD is pro-actively reserving the right to do anything silly. I note that linux says, "future calls will overwrite", not "future calls from the same thread will overwrite" - does linux in fact use a per-thread buffer, or a global one?

Comment: Using a per-thread buffer would be a waste of memory, but I wouldn't put it past glibc to do something like that. These interfaces are (1) deprecated, and (2) cannot be used portably in threaded code, so they should simply be optimized for unobtrusiveness in modern programs that don't use them.

Comment: Another "silly" option: On 64-bit machines, it could return a pointer into a string table of `static const` strings for every possible IPv4 address. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't free it. It's usually static storage within the function, or thread-specific data if you're running in a threaded environment.

From [the definitive POSIX man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html):

> The  return  value  of `inet_ntoa()` may point to static data that may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `inet_ntoa()`.

That page also states:

> The inet_ntoa() function need not be reentrant. A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe.

That means that, even in a threaded environment, it may not be thread-safe *at all.*

In other words, it can be implemented something like:

```
char *inet_ntoa (struct in_addr xyz) {
    static char buff[50];
    // Do something with xyz to populate buff.
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: The POSIX page says that it is not required to be thread-safe, but your answer indicates otherwise. Can you clarify things?

Comment: It's not required to be thread-safe, no, hence my use of the word "usual" (applying to both the static-storage and thread-specific parts of that sentence). I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to free it since it is static.

But you have to take a copy of the string contents before you call the function again, otherwise you'll overwrite the contents from the first call.